# A geometry problem with a cube (solid geometry)

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, solid-geometry

I ask you to solve this problem, because in the book and I have different answers

Point $M$ is the midpoint of the edge $AB$ of the cube $ABCDA_1B_1C_1D_1$. Find the distance between the straight lines $A_1M$ and $B_1C$, given that the edge of the cube is equal to $a$.

Please help me. It's Translated from Russian and it's the full context of the problem.

Comment: What is the book's answer, what is your answer and how did you arrive at your solution?

Comment: @player3236, I added

Comment: The answer in book has dimension of $\sqrt{ \text{Length} }$ which is ofcourse wrong. Are you sure you're presenting the answers correctly?

Comment: I edited the supposedly correct answer to $\sqrt6 a/3$, which is right, instead of $6\sqrt{a}/3$, which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be the point on $A_1M$ such that $A_1H/HM=2$, and $K$ be the point on $B_1C$ such that $CK/KB_1=2$. Then it is not difficult to show that segment $HK$ is perpendicular to both $A_1M$ and $B_1C$ and is thus the distance between the lines.

To compute the length of $HK$ it may be useful to note that $HK={2\over3}GF$, where $G$ and $F$ are the midpoints of $A_1A$ and $B_1C_1$ respectively.

[image]

Comment: Only thing I'm not quite seeing is, by solving right triangle FA_1G with hypotenuse GF why isn't $len(GF) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}a$ and therefore $len(HK)=  \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}a$ according to your solution?

Comment: @Circulwyrd Yes, $HK$ has length $\sqrt{2/3}$. Why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @Circulwyrd $FG=\sqrt{(1/2)^2+1^2+(1/2)^2}=\sqrt{3/2}$ and $HK=2/3 GF=\sqrt{2/3}$ (I set $a=1$).

Comment: I was referencing the given solution by the OP, as being the book's solution, (6√a)/3 aka 2√a. As [@]cosmos pointed out in another comment, there seems to be a possiblilty the answer is not presented correctly by OP, or is incorrect in book. I don't see anything wrong with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

HINTS

[image]

Take cube edges as parallel to x-,y-, z- axes.

Use vectors to find position vectors of red lines.

Normalize for length. Minimum distance lies along their cross product to find distance between *skew vectors*.

Comment: Please, can you specify your answer?